# Add male pin headers in DesignSpark PCB

Tags: pcb, design, header

I've been struggling with this software to find male pin header connectors but I could not find it even on the online database, has anyone an idea ? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is: [do it yourself](http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/eng/tutorial/components-creation-with-symbol-footprint-wizards?/designspark/electronics/tutorial/components-creation-with-symbol-footprint-wizards=) (RTM)

Comment: I used design spark. If you cant find a part in the library, open up the datasheet for the component you want to use and design it yourself. Design spark makes it very easy with the design wizards it provides.

Answer (score 2):

Design Spark has full capability to let you create your own schematic and layout symbols. Use that capability.